# button.setColorFilter not working

Tags: android, imagebutton

I have a code that changes the tint of an image button when clicked.

Here's the java code

```
 button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me) 
        {
            if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) 
            {

                button.setColorFilter(Color.argb(150, 155, 155, 155));

            } 

            else if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) 

            {
                button.setColorFilter(Color.argb(0, 155, 155, 155)); 
                }
            return false;
        }

    });
```

The code is working fine on this xml, the button dims when clicked.

```
  <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/schedule"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="138dp"
    android:layout_y="169dp"
    android:src="@drawable/schedule"
    />
```

But it is not working on this xml, the button doesn't dim when clicked.

```
  <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/schedule"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="138dp"
    android:layout_y="169dp"
    android:background="@drawable/schedule"
    />
```

Why does if I use android:background the setColorFilter doesn't work? but if I use android:src it is working fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simple answer is that:

- the `android:background` attribute refers to a method of the View class,
- `android:src` refers to a methods of ImageView,

and each class maintains their own background resources. So when you call the ImageView method `setColorFilter()`, it applies the filter to its local background resource (the one set by `src`) and `setColorFilter()` has no knowledge of the View resource set by `background`.